# Error Starting Xamarin Project

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i want to make a project with xamarin but in first place when i create a portable xamarin.forms blank project. I ran into this warnings and i do not know how to fix it

[image: warnings before update]

and when i update my visual it get even worst it's really making me angry
would you plz help me

[image: errors and warnings after update]

and if you tell me any tutorials that i can use for learning xamarin i appreciate that .

Answer (score 1):

Your current project target doesn't support some NuGet packages, so you must install the right Android SDK and Build Tools, and choose it in your project properties:

1. Download SDK and build tools

[image]

[image]

[image]

2. Change your project target:

[image]

[image]